# How to create a vertical div which fill entire screen?

Tags: css

I have four DIVs :

- The first div has a fixed height and located on top (header).
- The second div also has a fixed height and located below the first div.
- The fourth div has a fixed height located on bottom.
- The third div will have a variable height: it will expand to make the total of four divs are full to vertical space in browser IF the content is less than that. But it will follow the content's height if the content's height is larger than that. So at all times, I want the first div (the header) to stick at the top of the page, and the fourth div (the footer) to stick at the bottom of the page. I have no way to know how tall the content will be.

  header
      header
      header
      header

the CSS file:

```
#container { width:800px; height:*; }
#header    { height:200px; }
#menu      { height:50px; }
#content   { height:*; }
#footer    { height:150px; }
```

can I actually do this? how is the correct css way to do this? I get the feeling this should be not too hard, but I can't find relatable answers anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this:

```
#content { height: 100vh; /*100% of viewport height*/
     margin-top: 250px;
     margin-bottom: 150px; }
```

This way it will always be 100% of the screen height in total.

Comment: css has value unit measurement like that?? wow I genuinely have just know that. I thought it only has percent and px.. okay let me try. btw, is that from CSS3?

Comment: there is some problem. the result of the header + menu + content + footer is indeed = 100vh. but the container now is 100vh + (250px + 150px) tall. it seems like when the margin top and margin bottom is changed, the content's actual height is not changed, so the container's height now grow to accommodate the non-existent (or invisible?) content's height.

Answer (score 0):

Well that turned out looking cool, 

## JSBin

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">Header !</div>
<div class="menu">Menu !</div>
<div class="content">Content !</div>
<div class="footer">Footer !</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body       { margin: 0; }
.header    { width: 100%; height: 200px; position: fixed; top: 0;        }
.menu      { width: 100%; height: 50px;  position: fixed; top: 200px;    }
.footer    { width: 100%; height: 150px; position: fixed; bottom: 0;     }
.content   { width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 250px; bottom: 150px;
             overflow: auto;                                             }
```

Comment: ow this is another way to do this, but the result is different! the scrolling one is only the content. The one I actually need is what @Max Langerak has answered, but I might need this too in the future! Thank you very much!